# No of ways of making a selection.

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are $n$ different books and $p$ copies of each. Find the number of ways in which a selection can be made.
My attempt: When he says, make a selection, I assumed that one book is to be selected.Isn't $n*(pC1)$ the answer? Apparently $((p+1)^n)-1$ is the answer. Where have I gone wrong? My assumption?

Comment: From the answer it looks like he means any selection that isn't 0 books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is meant here: in how many ways can you select k books? Apparently $1 \leq k \leq np$. The main trick is to take into account the fact that each book (you have n books) has p indistinguishable copies. Say book 1 has p=4 copies numbered 1,2,3,4. Now if k=3, while picking k=3 books you can pick for example:

book 1 / copy 1
book 1 / copy 2
book 1 / copy 3

or

book 1 / copy 2
book 1 / copy 3
book 1 / copy 4

but these two don't count as different selections.

Each selection you make can be encoded with a vector of n integers:

$(k_1, k_2, ..., k_n)$

where each number $k_s$ shows how many copies of book $s$ you took (in this selection).

The count of these vectors is $(p+1)^n$ (as you have $(p+1)$ options for each $k_s$). The vector with zeros only is invalid (as it does not represent any selection). So you get $(p+1)^n-1$ as a final answer.

Answer (score 4):

For each book we have $p+1$ choices: we can pick one of the $p$ books or we can choose to leave it out. Now we do this $n$ times so this gives
$$
(p+1)^n
$$
combinations. However, the one combination of choices where you do not pick any books should be left out, so we obtain
$$
(p+1)^n-1
$$
as wanted.

Comment: i get the (p+1) choices part but we have n different books and we actually choose only one at any time. So, why are we multiplying the number of possibilities n times instead of just adding them n times?

Comment: Okay, let's first do this with $n=2$. We have $p+1$ choices for the first book and $p+1$ for the second book. If we would draw a tree diagram this gives $p+1$ branches at the first node and then again $p+1$ branches at every node on the right and side. Therefore we obtain $(p+1)^2$ possibilities.

Comment: OK.So, you chose one book of each kind?

Comment: Well, for each book we actually have $p+1$ options, because we can choose to leave it out of our set of books.